# Directives like ng-click, ng-onmoseover are not working in child elements generated in Angular's controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to anglarjs. My problem description :-

My html -

```
<div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
    <div id="wrapperElement"></div>
</div>
```

Angular Controller - (not working)

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var nodeDivTag = '<div ng-click="sampleFunction()">Click Me</div>';
    $("#wrapperElement").append(nodeDivTag);

    $scope.sampleFunction = function(){
        alert("Costom message");
    };
}]);
```

Angular Controller - (working)

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var nodeDivTag = '<div onclick="sampleFunction()">Click Me</div>';
    $("#wrapperElement").append(nodeDivTag);

    sampleFunction = function(){
        alert("Costom message");
    };
}]);
```

ng-click is not working when I am appending the child element in the controller. onclick is working at the same place. ng-click is even working when I am using it in the wrapperElement like this

```
<div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
    <div id="wrapperElement" ng-click="sampleFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

and controller used is the not working one. Can anyone help me out here how to use ng-click in appended child element or why its not working in this case.

Comment: HTML within a Controller? None of this should be happening in the first place. These should be within directive templates.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS is correct. You will very likely want to move the DOM manipulation into a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to compile the element prior to adding it to the DOM. Something like this (not tested)

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {
    var nodeDivTag = $compile('<div ng-click="sampleFunction()">Click Me</div>')($scope);
    $("#wrapperElement").append(nodeDivTag);

    sampleFunction = function(){
        alert("Costom message");
    };
}]);
```